# Why aren't my Spring import statements working?

Tags: spring, intellij-14

[image]

None of my import statements are working. I am making the project in IntelliJ

I have included this in my pom.xml 
[image]

Comment: Is this in a test class?

Answer (score 1):

Because you are importing spring test artifact in your pom.xml
 and you try to import spring package classes

```
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
<scope>test</scope>
```

Try adding

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```